# Should Migration options in off topic include mathematics educators?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

It seems to me that [questions like this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736255/middle-school-mathematics) belong to Mathematics Educators and there will be occasional others where migrating like this will be the best thing to do.

There are various threads on migration options, and advantages and disadvantages - I think this option would make it easier to manage the site.

Comment: I think before we do this, we would have to establish that questions on math education are off topic here. I'm not sure that is the case currently.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks- I mainly wanted to put the case, because the list seemed limited. And I also agree that there is a place for some questions of this kind on this site, and there ought to be a fuzzy boundary rather than a sharp one.

Comment: The list is limited mostly because there are not many posts on Math.SE that are both off-topic here **and** are on-topic somewhere else on the network. [Grace Note](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12963/127096) gave the statistics on this recently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While such questions may be on topic on Mathematics Educators, remember that MathEd.SE is a *very* young public beta site. Generally migrating questions to beta sites is at least slightly discouraged.  In the words of [Anna Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169984/214632):

> Migrating to beta sites isn't something we encourage because beta should be all about a site figuring out its own voice rather than getting questions from elsewhere, but an occasional migration doesn't hurt much.

and echoed by [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191348/214632)

> ...and we're very much against establishing migration paths to beta sites, we need to be absolutely sure that they're going to graduate before we facilitate a conduit for content to go to them.

While eventually a migration path would perhaps be natural, I think that for the time being stemming the potential flow by requiring migrations go through the ♦-moderators (who may then also contact the [newly appointed *pro tem* ♦-moderators](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/253) of MathEd.SE about worthiness/desirability of such questions) is a better option.

Comment: Also, MathEd.SE is such a new site that many people don't know about it. One should _definitely_ add a comment pointing out the existence of the other site. Awareness is what allows the sites to grow and graduate; awareness is also how we can prevent off-topic questions.

Comment: Just a remark that MathEd.SE is now a more mature beta site, having been running for over two years. Might that also influence consideration for a migration path?

Answer (score 6):

I agree. In the mean time, remember that moderators can migrate questions to any site, so if you think a question belongs on a site not among the default migration targets, flag it.