# Option to migrate questions to matheducators.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

In the past couple of days I've noticed an upswing in questions about math education rather than math, frequently of the sort *Why should math students learn about [topic]*? (Here's an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571481/why-should-students-who-wont-need-university-level-math-still-study-math-and-n).)

Would it be worthwhile to add an option to flag these questions as off-topic and recommend they be moved to [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)? I could understand why not, especially if math-education questions asked on math.SE tend to be low-quality, but the idea seemed at least plausible enough to moot.

Comment: Older discussion: [Should Migration options in off topic include mathematics educators?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13281) (it was a few years back, when Mathematics Educators was a very young site.) Still, I am not sure to which extent migration paths to beta sites are reasonable. Anyway, since there is a user who is moderato bothr here and on Mathematics Educators, I suppose they are in very good position to make a reasonable call about this.

Comment: I have voted to close this as a duplicate of the recent discussion on the topic of migration as I feel that the answers there fully address why there are only the three options that there currently are. I would like to reiterate (as mentioned on that answer) that you can migrate any post to any SE by flagging it for mod attention.

Comment: I think that kind of questions are a better fit here. After all, here we have plenty of people who have used various kinds of math in various places - exactly the kind of people who can describe motivating example applications. In MathEducators.SE the place is largely populate by educators (!!). They are usually not in possession of such pieces of information. True, there is variety there also, but this is a bigger site, and IMHO that is beneficial here.