# Why are there so few migration options?

Tags: discussion, migration

> **Question I**: Why are there *only three* options for migrating off-topic posts that are on the wrong StachExchange. And why exactly these three. It seems a bit arbitrary.

The current options are migration to

- Physics StachExchange,
- Statistics Stackexchange and
- Meta.Mathematics StackExchange?

What about migration to:

- Mathematical Educator,
- History of Science and Mathematics,
- Philosophy,
- Cryptography,
- Comptuer Science,
- Theoretical Computer Science,
- Mathematica
- ...

Is it that there are too few questions which actually need these options? Are there really so many for Statistics.SE? I can imagine some of the above to be at least as important as Statistics.SE.

> **Question II**: What if a question *really* belongs to another not listed StackExchange? Can a moderator migrate to all other sides? Do I just flag for moderator intervention?

Comment: Only a limited number can be defined.  Others must be done by flagging and getting a diamond guy to do it.  If there are many cases of a given migration target (so far only those listed meet that criterion) maybe another will be added.

Comment: Did you search meta at all? If so, how did you miss [this recent thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27593/11619)? (earlier variants linked to from there).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes I searches. Quite a bit actually. Seems to me more like a flaw of the "search engine". What search terms you used to find it? Maybe the problem was that I sorted by votes. But *many thanks* for the link.

Comment: Yeah, the search engine kinda sucks. Sorry about being cranky. But, two most recent threads in the tag [meta-tag:migration] were both on this theme.

Comment: You (and other 10k+rep users) can see the stats [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats).